# FHIR: Get all encounters, patients, appointments for the practice

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to use FHIR to pull all patients, encounters and appointments into an intermediate database for further analysis.  Most of the FHIR API's appear to be designed to handle one patient ID at a time, or one encounter at a time, etc.  What is the most efficient way to pull the full set of encounters and then keep it current, as well as appointments, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You should provide some foundation for the solution proposals, as close as you can get to a [mcve] for your problem. You should also demonstrate your own effort, e.g. be showing the inefficient solutions you found. Then asking for hints at contained performance wasters would be appropriate.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the FHIR specification website, specifically the page about [the RESTFul API](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/http.html) and look at search. The APIs have methods to support the interactions described on the website.

Comment: I see from this reference that FHIR supports a paging mechanism for bringing back large datasets:

Comment: That answers how to receive these large data sets.  What about the query?  From other reading, I would first query for encounters or appointments, and tell FHIR to return the patient resources along with the encounter resources.  We want to go back 7 years and get everything in these tables.  Does FHIR support a query that allows me to say, "give me every encounter for every patient at this practice in this date range?"  From the specification, I can't tell if this would be supported.

Comment: Yes, FHIR does support this, but of course it depends on the system implementation if the system will answer your query.